# Get the worksheet of the button which called the macro

Tags: excel, vba

In a VBA macro, how do I get the worksheet object where the button which called the macro is located?

I tried for example

```vb
ActiveSheet.shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Worksheet.Name
```

but I obviously need to not use `ActiveSheet` for obtaining it.

Comment: Well, if the shape was clicked, it is on the active sheet...

Comment: @GSerg what if the shape was clicked programmaticaly?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I do not know how to programmatically invoke the Click event on an Excel `Shape` object. If the click was simulated via the mouse input, then again, the sheet is active.

Comment: Yes I'm currently using 'Activesheet' in my macroes that must process the rows under the calling button but I'm wondering if this is a 100% solid assumption...

Comment: could you show us the line that clicks the button or shape that calls the procedure?

Comment: Is this an X-Y problem? Because in Excel you can have two "Button 1", each on separate sheets, there is no easy way to separate them if they call the same macro - as you have already discovered, `Application.Caller` does not provide the right information to do the job. At this stage `ActiveSheet` appears to be the best way (but I would assign `Set ws = ActiveSheet` and then do the `Application.Caller` stuff). For example, if you put the functions into a custom menu, and used the `Before_RightClick` event handler, you get access to all the calling range information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for AJD words, "at this stage ActiveSheet appears to be the best way"